# Function to check if entered number is a prime is broken though nothing seems to be wrong with the code

Tags: c, for-loop

I was learning how to use 'switch' and was writing a program to do various functions and everything else is working except the function that checks if the entered program in a prime.

I really can't seem to find the problem with the code here, is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x, c = 1, a, l;

    printf("1. Factorial\n2. Prime or not\n3. Even or Odd\n4. Exit\nWhat would you like to do? ");

    while (c != 4)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &c);
        switch (c)
        {
        case 1:
            a = 1;
            scanf_s("%d", &x);
            for (l = 1; l <= x; l++)
                a = a * l;
            printf("Factorial of %d = %d\n", x, a);
            break;
        case 2:
            scanf_s("%d", &x);
            for (l = 1; l <= x; l++)
            {
                if (x % l == 0 && l != x)
                {
                    printf("The number entered is not a prime.\n");
                    break;
                }
                else if (l == x)
                {
                    printf("The number entered is a prime.\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            scanf_s("%d", &x);
            if (x % 2 == 0)
                printf("The number entered is even.\n");
            else
                printf("The number entered is odd.\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            exit();
        }
        printf("\n1. Factorial\n2. Prime or not\n3. Even or Odd\n4. Exit\nWhat would you like to do? ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask youself what is `x % 1`. (Aside: that is '"one" not "ell", the first loop iteration. Never use `l` (ell) as  variable name it looks too much like `1` (one) and every time I see a `1` I have to think is that an `l` or is it `1` and every time I see an `l` I have to think is that a `1` or is it `l` ).

Comment: You missed the case of `x % l == 0 && x==l`

Comment: To be clear, on the first iteration `if (x % 1 == 0 && 1 != x)` is always true unless `x == 1`.

Comment: @Chronos The code snippet outputs nothing if the user will enter 0.